# Crontab for sending mails

Tags: python, linux, django, cron

I created my send_newsletter admin commands with django, when i'm using the

```
python manage.py send_newsletter
```

it works.
My send_newsletter.py

```
sys.path.append('/srv/apps/')  
sys.path.append('%s/actecil_newsletter' % os.getcwd())  
sys.path.append('%s/actecil_newsletter/actecil_newsletter' % os.getcwd())  
sys.path.append('/srv/apps/apps_django_1_4') 
sys.path.append('/srv/apps/apps_django_1_4/Django-1.4.3') 
if 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' not in os.environ.keys():
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

class Command(BaseCommand):
  args = '<mail_id, mail_id, ...>'
  def handle(self, *args, **options):   
    mail = Mail.objects.all()
    for mail in mail:
        print "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
        if not mail.sended :
            soup = BeautifulSoup(mail.content)
            subject = mail.subject
            recipients = []
            for t in mail.tags.all():
                for r in t.recipients.all():
                    if not r in recipients:
                        recipients.append(r)

            for r in mail.recipients.all():
                if not r in recipients:
                    recipients.append(r)

            if recipients:
                for a in soup.find_all('a'):
                    link = Link()
                    link.link = (a.get('href'))
                    link.mail = mail
                    link.save()
                    a['href'] = "%s/compagnes/link/%s/%s/%s/" % (settings.WEBSITE_URL, mail.id, '-*{^@+*@=)=-+*-=+*-=*+=--=*-*=-==)@@###/+@]}-*', link.id)
                tag = soup.new_tag('img', src="%s/compagnes/mail/%s/%s/" % (settings.WEBSITE_URL, mail.id, '-*{^@+*@=)=-+*-=+*-=*+=--=*-*=-==)@@###/+@]}-*'))
                soup.body.insert_after(tag)
                content = soup.prettify()
                for r in recipients:
                    c = content.replace('-*{^@+*@=)=-+*-=+*-=*+=--=*-*=-==)@@###/+@]}-*', "%s" % r.id)
                    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject.encode('utf-8'), c.encode('utf-8'), settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [r.mail, ])
                    msg.attach_alternative(c, "text/html")
                    msg.send()
            mail.sended = True      
            mail.date_sent = datetime.datetime.now()
            mail.save()
```

I created a cron with

```
sudo crontab -e
```

on the Terminal and put this in the crontab file :

```
*/5 * * * * cd /srv/apps/newsletter/actecil_newsletter && python manage.py send_newsletter
```

But it doesn't work, if someone know how to fix it ?

EDIT : I got this error in the log of the crontab

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

Comment: Could be lots of things.  Cron should send you email when it fails; if you're not getting that email you can redirect the output by adding `>/tmp/log 2>&1` to the end of the cron job and look at the file for errors.

Comment: I think you are using ubuntu and in ubuntu crontab is running but unfortunately django code not get executed. I suggest you use django-celery for that.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I added the error log in the question.

Comment: Looks like `PYTHONPATH` may be set for you but not for cron?

Comment: I added the sys.path used in the send_newsletter.py file and put in in the manage.py and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnaly found how to fix my problem thanks everyone for trying to help me.
After getting the logs (thanks to John Zwinck), i added this to my manage.py

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/django/apps_django_1_4')
sys.path.append('/path/to/django/apps_django_1_4/Django-1.4.3')
sys.path.append('%s/actecil_newsletter' % os.getcwd())
sys.path.append('%s/actecil_newsletter/actecil_newsletter' % os.getcwd())
```

This made it work, hope it will help someone else then me :)

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that python running in cron can't access the django installation. There is many questions about that, How is Django installed in your system ? (with SO package, pip, or by hand..).

Use [django-cron](https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron) will make your life much easier, simplify your development and manage all your app in a django-way ;)

Tips:

- In Django development you must use [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- Consider read about Task/Queue jobs like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try running the cron job as a specific user? When I started out with django, I had issues with  django admin commands and cron jobs as well. Since then, I usually run as a specific user

```
*/5 * * * * su -l <user> -c cd /srv/apps/newsletter/actecil_newsletter && python manage.py send_newsletter
```